# backbone.validation plugin. Validation doesn't work on model

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone.validation.js

I try to to use Backbone.validation plugin. 
Here is a link to this plugin. 
https://github.com/thedersen/backbone.validation.

I want to start a validation, when I create a new model instance. Normally in Backbone should implement a **validate** function and then when we should pass **{validate:true}**

How achieve the same result with this plugin?

```
   //create picture instance in a controller 
    var model = new Picture({
            name: file.name,
            size: file.size, 
            type: file.type
     }, {validate: true} );
```

```
//Picture class
export default Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        name: "",
        size: null, 
        type: ""
    },
    validation: {
        size: function (size) {
            if(size > this.MAX_FILE_SIZE;) {
                return this.onFileSizeError()
            }
            return '';
        },
        onFileSizeError() {
             //execute this when model size is wrong
        }

});
```

Comment: Probably is necessary to use _.extend(Backbone.Model.prototype,Backbone.Validation.mixin);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Problem solved**

So in a plugin documentation is information about validation on model without binding with a view.

> Using model validation
>
> The philosophy behind this way of using the plugin, is to give you an
>   easy way to implement validation across all your models without the
>   need to bind to a view. Of course, if you use this option the
>   callbacks to update the view is not executed, since there is no way of
>   knowing what view a model belongs to.
>
> Validation mix-in
>
> To add validation to your models, mix in the validation on the Model's
>   prototype.
>
> ```
>  _.extend(Backbone.Model.prototype, Backbone.Validation.mixin);
> ```

So we can create a file with a base model which will be extend Backbone.Model.prototype. Now each new class should be extended by our class Model.

From now we can use a validation.plugin on our instance